# set input as readonly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, readonly

I am currently trying to create a JS method which sets a specific input field as readonly if another field contains a value inside it but i am having issues with getting it to work.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    const priceInputs = $('.price input');
    priceInputs.change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ''){
            $(this).parents('.price').find('input').attr('readonly', false);
            $(this).attr('readonly', false);
        }else{
            $(this).parents('.price').find('input').attr('readonly', true);
        }
    });
});
```

but when i load a record which contains a value inside it the other field isn't automatically set to readonly

anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: So is it that your html page has 2 input. And on having value in 1st input box you want the 2nd input box to be `readonly`?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML so we can see this in action.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yeah thats correct, and vice versa if the value is inside the 2nd input box set the 1st input to readonly

Comment: Your code works already. I am adding a text in one field and as soon as I move out of it, all input fields become readonly. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Use each loop for class elements.

```js
$('.price').each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
    console.log(this.value)
    if (this.value === '') {
      $('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('readonly', false);
    } else {
      $('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
      this.readOnly = false;

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="input1" class="price" />
<input type="text" name="input2" class="price" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing the readonly property you should use prop() like below:

```
$("#name").prop('readonly', false);
```